# calculating the mean and se of data based on multiple variables in an unbalanced design

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate some summary stats on a data set where the units of interest do not appear in every event but it is important to consider every event in calculations such as the mean. I have the following data (t2)

```
ca  cat spp eg  len cou
a1  bd  a   y   62  1
a1  bd  a   y   63  2
a1  bd  a   y   66  1
a1  br  b   y   260 1
a2  bd  a   y   61  1
a2  bd  a   y   62  1
a2  bd  b   y   200 1
a2  bd  b   y   201 1
a2  bd  c   y   55  1
a2  bd  c   y   50  2
a3  mr  a   n   66  1
a3  bd  a   n   60  1
a3  bd  a   n   59  1
a3  bd  c   n   50  1
a4  mr  a   n   66  1
a4  mr  a   n   67  1
a5  bd  a   n   64  1
```

I am able to calculate overall means

```
t2 %>% 
  mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>% 
  group_by(spp) %>% 
  summarise(av = sum(cou)/first(nca))
```

returning

```
spp av
a   2.4         
b   0.6         
c   0.8
```

but I haven't had success when, calculating the mean grouped by levels of eg due to their being a lack of balance between ca and eg. This is what I tried

```
t2 %>% 
  group_by(eg) %>% 
  mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>% 
  group_by(spp, eg) %>% 
  summarise(av = sum(cou)/first(nca))
```

returning

```
spp eg    av
a   n   2.0000000       
a   y   3.0000000       
b   y   1.5000000       
c   n   0.3333333       
c   y   1.5000000
```

obviously only the y levels are correct. Any help to do this succinctly with standard error would be appreciated (preferably using dplyr).

The correct data would look like

```
cat    spp    av    eg
bd  a   3.0000000   y   
bd  b   1.0000000   y   
bd  c   1.5000000   y   
br  b   0.5000000   y   
bd  a   1.0000000   n   
bd  c   0.3333333   n   
mr  a   1.0000000   n
```

which I calculated by splitting the data by eg (y or n) calculating the statistics and rejoining

```
t2y<- t2 %>% 
  filter(eg%in%"y") %>%
  mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>%  
  group_by(cat, spp) %>% 
  summarise(av=sum(cou/nca))%>% 
  mutate(eg="y")

t2n<- t2 %>% 
  filter(eg%in%"n") %>%
  mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>%  
  group_by(cat, spp) %>% 
  summarise(av=sum(cou/nca)) %>% 
  mutate(eg="n")

full_join(t2y, t2n)
```

a more succinct approach would be useful!

Comment: Could you specify what is your expected output?

Comment: the same as above but the eg n would be 1.0 for spp a (for example) due to being weighted correctly by the number of ca that have eg = N (i.e. 3)

Comment: Can you explain the calculation to be used to calculate correct `av` ?

Comment: t2 %>% 
  filter(eg%in%"n") %>%
  mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>%  
  group_by(cat, spp) %>% 
  summarise(av=sum(cou/nca)) %>% 
  mutate(eg="n")

Comment: It is still not clear to me how are you are performing the calculation or what values your final output should have.

Comment: have made edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just fail to include `cat` in the group by?

```r
t2 %>%
    group_by(eg) %>%
    mutate(nca=n_distinct(ca)) %>%
    group_by(cat, spp, eg) %>%
    summarise(av = sum(cou)/first(nca)) %>%
    arrange(desc(eg))
```

It gives:

```
  cat   spp   eg       av
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 bd    a     y     3    
2 bd    b     y     1    
3 bd    c     y     1.5  
4 br    b     y     0.5  
5 bd    a     n     1    
6 bd    c     n     0.333
7 mr    a     n     1
```